# cordova-plugin-fcm Difference between FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh() and FCMPlugin.getToken()

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic2

Im developing an ionic application and im using push notifications. I find the cordova-plugin-fcm plugin and was wondering which is the difference between FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh() and FCMPlugin.getToken() methods.

In firebase documentation it seems that both are used in tandem to get the token. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es-419)